# Explanation for this assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

```
void* curbrk;

__asm__ __volatile__(
    "mov .curbrk, %%rax;"
    "mov %%rax, %0"
        : "=r" (curbrk)
        :: "%rax"
);
```

Can anyone explain what this simple assembly code does? Thanks.

Comment: As it is, nothing in particular. `.curbrk` doesn't refer to a register, label or otherwise meaningful symbol.

Comment: So what is it, then? That's what I'm not able to figure out too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It copies the value of a symbol `.curbrk`, probably defined somewhere on assembly or a linker script into the C variable `curbrk`, clobbering the `RAX` register in the process.

`.curbrk` probably points to the current end of the data segment. Glibc appears to define a similar symbol `__curbrk`, you are probably using some other libc (BSD?). In any case, `sbrk(0)` would be a more portable way of accessing that value.

After looking at the FreeBSD crossreference, I can say it indeed points to the current end of the data segment: it is used both in [`brk()`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/7.0.0/lib/libc/amd64/sys/brk.S?view=markup#l41) and [`sbrk()`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/7.0.0/lib/libc/amd64/sys/sbrk.S?view=markup#l41), using the [HIDENAME](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/amd64/include/asm.h?v=FREEBSD-12-STABLE#L50) macro to prepend a `.`, and it appears on [amd64's System.map](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/7.0.0/lib/libc/amd64/Symbol.map?view=markup#l67) (no longer true on current FreeBSD).

Note, however, that in newer FreeBSD, `brk()` and `sbrk()` have been reimplemented to no longer depend of `.curbrk`, which was initialized from `_end`, which was supposed to come from the executable, but there was trouble when mixing LLVM's ld and GNU ld. So `brk()` and `sbrk()` now use the kernel to initialize its internal `curbrk`, and no longer depend on `_end`. See [FreeBSD PR228754](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228574) for details.

Comment: Ya, exactly :) I'm using FreeBSD. [I too thought .curbrk mite be a compiler-defined variable probably pointing to the end of DS, tried googling it, but couldn't find any info.]. And how do I access the end of data segment with brk(0) - brk doesn't return any pointer and won't brk(0) shrink the program's data segment to 0.

Comment: @Raj Kumar: oops, sorry, I meant `sbrk(0)`.

Comment: @Raj: also, DS probably has nothing to do with this at all. DS and the other selectors are probably set to provide a flat address space, and limits are enforced via paging, as is traditional in *nix.

Comment: Yeah, sbrk(0) could be used to access the current system break. But the code I posted was actually the code for sbrk I was trying to implement myself. (So, Calling sbrk(0) from sbrk will be pointless). I was looking for some other way to do that.

Comment: I assume when you said _It copies the value of a symbol `.value`,_ you meant `.curbrk`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I dunno what I was thinking about 9 years ago, but I guess so. Took the chance to update links and add some commentary on current changes that make this whole question/answer obsolete, and only of historical interest.

Answer (score 0):

Copy value into `%%rax` from `.curbrk` label or variable